# Generating RSA Key Pairs Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to find a good library to do the following:

1. Generate RSA public and private key pairs
2. Encrypt / decrypt using keys
3. Sign using private key / verify with public key
4. Generate SHA256 hashes

I tried many libraries, but I can't seem to find something simple and straightforward with all these functions. In python [pycrypto](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/) covers all this, it's really strange that there doesn't seem to be something like this available for Swift.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using iOS 13 or above as the base SDK for your app then you should look at CryptoKit from Apple as it should cover what you are looking for.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit

If you need to support devices running versions of iOS older than iOS13 then you should look at CommonCrypto (also native to Apple) but if you can afford to only support iOS13 and above then CryptoKit is far better and easier to implement.

Comment: RSA keys are unsupported by CryptoKit